# Javascript moving my Node6 Firebase function to Node8 async/await pattern

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

As firebase functions now run w Node8, I would like to transform my current ES5 function w Promise flow to ES6 async/await

my flow pattern is the following :

```
const AUTHORIZED = authorizedApi()
  if AUTHORIZED
      const SENT = sendContactMessage())
      if SENT
          const FOUND = findContact(
              if FOUND
                  return "FINISHED"
                  if !FOUND
                      const CREATED = createContact()
                      if CREATED
                          return "FINISHED"
```

Currently I am using a specific conditionalPromiseFlow() function as following : ( need to handle also the errors..

```
const conditionalPromiseFlow = (...fns) => {
  if (fns.length === 0) return Promise.resolve();
  const [next] = fns;
  return next().then(result => {
    if (result) {
      return conditionalPromiseFlow(...fns.slice(1));
    }
    return result;
  });
};
```

and I call it  :

```
conditionalPromiseFlow(
  () => authorizedApi(jwtClient),
  () => sendContactMessage(gmailAPI, encodedContactMessage),
  () =>
    findContact(
      googlePeopleAPI.connections,
      googleConnectionListParams,
      sender.email
    ),
  () => createContact(googlePeopleAPI, googlePeopleContactParams)
)
  .then(
    res => {
      return { status: 200, infos: "done" };
    },
    error => {
      return { status: error.status, infos: error.message };
    }
  )
  .then(response => {
    return res.send(response);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

this runs well, but I guess that async/await pattern would simplify my code...  Is it true or should I stick to my current code ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is **not** contained in an `async` function, the `async`/`await` equivalent would be:

```
(async() => {
  try {
    await authorizedApi(jwtClient);
    await sendContactMessage(gmailAPI, encodedContactMessage);
    await findContact(
      googlePeopleAPI.connections,
      googleConnectionListParams,
      sender.email
    );
    await createContact(googlePeopleAPI, googlePeopleContactParams);
    res.send({ status: 200, infos: "done" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({ status: error.status, infos: error.message });
  }
))();
```

Whether that's simpler and a change worth making is obviously up to you.

(From your code, I take it when the promises returned by those functions reject, the object they provide has a `status` on it.)

Note that I didn't put a `try`/`catch` around the last `res.send`. I don't think it throws, but you did have a `catch` handler on it. So if it throws, you'd want to put that back.

If you're *already* in an `async` function, obviously you don't need that `async` wrapper:

```
try {
  await authorizedApi(jwtClient);
  await sendContactMessage(gmailAPI, encodedContactMessage);
  await findContact(
    googlePeopleAPI.connections,
    googleConnectionListParams,
    sender.email
  );
  await createContact(googlePeopleAPI, googlePeopleContactParams);
  res.send({ status: 200, infos: "done" });
} catch (error) {
  res.send({ status: error.status, infos: error.message });
}
```

By `res.send` it seems like You're using express framework - so You can make handler to be async wrapper, it's enough to put `async` word before `(req, res)`:

```
app.get('/something', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    /*
    await stuff here
    */
    res.send({ status: 200, infos: "done" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({ status: error.status, infos: error.message });
  }
});
```

Note that both in the above and in the `async` wrapper in the first code block that the **entire** body is in the `try` (other than the `res.send` on error). That's because nothing will handle the promise from the `async`  function (Express doesn't do anything with the return value of route callbacks), so it's important that promise doesn't reject.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I to a better understanding of it now....  ( your right I am using an express framework...  this HTTP Firebase function is requested when a user send a Contact request ... it triggers some Google APIs functions... gmail to send the message to an admin, then check if the contact already exist in Firebase DB , if not create it...

Comment: @erwin - I didn't and arguably should have pointed you at http://koajs.com, which is the new framework from the same people that did Express which incorporates `async` functions at the framework level.